# When to use a directive, when a service and when a controller in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a bit confused on when to use what in angularjs. I know the basic concept of controller, service/factory and directive but I'm not sure what to use in my case.

Scenario: A form that allows a user to post a link. The form itself requests some information about the link from an external service and presents it immediately to the user. Posting is possible via the API of a NodeJS app (not that that matters). The form should be reusable so I want the code to be DRY. I don't like the use of ng-include since directives seem to be the way to go.

So far I have a factory to deal with requesting information (`linkservice`) and a factory to deal with creating posts (`posts`). I then use a directive with it's own controller to display the form and handle user actions. But I'm not sure if I should move the content of the directives' controller into a normal controller or even a service, since directives shouldn't deal with requesting data (as I understand). Or maybe this is already the right way.

**The Directive**

```
// The form to publish a new post
myModule.directive('postForm', [
  'linkservice',
  'posts',
  '$state',
  function(linkservice, posts, $state){
  return {
    templateUrl : '/js/app/views/partials/post-form.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.analyzeURL = function() {
        $scope.filtered_url = $scope.link.url.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?/gmi);
        if($scope.filtered_url !== null) {
          linkservice.extractURL($scope.filtered_url).then(function(res) {
            var website_info = res.data;
            $scope.link = {
              title: website_info.title,
              description: website_info.description,
              medium: website_info.provider_name,
              medium_thumbnail_url: website_info.favicon_url,
              url: $scope.filtered_url[0]
            }
            // Image
            if(website_info.images.length > 0 && website_info.images[0].width >= 500) {
              $scope.link.thumbnail_url = website_info.images[0].url;  
            } else { $scope.link.thumbnail_url = null; }
            // Keywords
            $scope.link.keywords = [];
            if(website_info.keywords.length >= 2) {
              $scope.link.keywords[0] = website_info.keywords[0].name;
              $scope.link.keywords[1] = website_info.keywords[1].name;
            }
            $scope.show_preview = true;
          });
        }
      },
      // addPost
      $scope.addPost = function(){
        if(!$scope.post || $scope.post.text === '' || !$scope.link || $scope.link.url === '') { return; }
        posts.create({
          post: $scope.post,
          link: $scope.link
        }).success(function() {
          delete $scope.post;
          delete $scope.link;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

**The template**

```
<form ng-submit="addPost()" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <h3>Add a new Post</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="URL"
      ng-model="link.url" ng-change="analyzeURL()"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea type="text"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Description / TLDR"
    ng-model="post.text" ></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="link.title"></input>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="link.description"></input>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="link.thumbnail_url"></input>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="link.medium"></input>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="link.medium_thumbnail_url"></input>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="link.keywords"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="lp-container" ng-show="show_preview">
    <span class="lp-provider"><img src="{{link.medium_thumbnail_url}}" class="lp-favicon">&nbsp;{{link.medium}}</span>
    <h2 class="lp-title">{{link.title}}</h2>
    <div class="lp-description">{{link.description}}</div>
    <img class="lp-thumbnail" ng-show="link.thumbnail_url" src="{{link.thumbnail_url}}">
    <div class="lp-keywords">
      <span ng-repeat="kw in link.keywords" class="lp-keyword">{{kw}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it, is to keep in mind that Angular is a MVVM-like framework.

Your **directives** define the **view**, how to print data, events, etc.

Your **services** are **singletons** so they are the best place to **store data** and to put all data management (web services requests, etc). As they will be instanciated only once, your data won't be duplicated.

Your **controllers** are instanciated each time you link them to a directive (ng-controller etc.). So you should avoid to store data here. Controllers should be used as **link between services and directives**. They could contains low-level data check etc, then call the services.

In your example you can simplify you code by moving your controller in another place to avoid to mix it all. Ex: Here your directive directly depends to `linkservice` when it's only the controller which needs it.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I know. But why is it then possible to create controllers within directives? And should I create a postForm controller AND a directive that displays said form? How would I wire this up so that every instance of the form keeps its scope and they are working together on one page?

Comment: Being able to create controllers within directives doesn't mean it is a good pattern. You can do it, but it's cleaner not to, especially when you have such complexity in your controller. I think you should split them, then link it with `controller: "formController"` in your directive. So each time you instanciate a directive `postForm` it will automaticaly instanciate a `formController` too.